# LibGDX touchDown event continues

Tags: libgdx, android-studio

I'm using libGdx to create a simple platformer.

I used a set of images as an onScreen controller for Android, and use this code to fire a shot ->

```
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            downPressed = true;
            return true;
            //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            downPressed = false;
            //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
```

But when I keep the button pressed, the player continues to shoot which I don't want, I want the player to tap-to-shoot.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the player continues to shoot is once you press the button **downPress=true**. It will stay true until you release the button. You could just call the shoot method from the touchDown event.

```
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            downPressed = true;
            ShootNow();
            return true;
            //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            downPressed = false;
            //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Gdx.input.justTouched()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched--) in your input loop to check for a tap event, then check if the Gdx.input.getX() and .getY() coordinates are within the bounds of any of your 'controller' images and respond accordingly.